# typescript enum string type an array of Object.keys

Tags: typescript

Is there a stricter way of typing

an array build with Object.keys ?

I mean instead using string[]

sort of (key in Languages)[]   ?

```
export enum Languages {
    de = 'de',
    en = 'en',
    fr = 'fr'
}

const langs: string[] = Object.keys(Languages);
```

Comment: Just a side note: [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) names are usually singular rather than plural, e.g. `Language` rather than `Languages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` is defined as returning `string[]` because it needs to be defined to handle the general case.

In your specific case, you can use a type assertion on the value `keys` returns:

```
const langs = Object.keys(Languages) as Languages[];
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=53&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIENEHNla7ADOcA3gFBzVwAmwcAvHAOT0sA0VNSTrSnbtQBmUPi1EsKAXwoUAxhETF4AGxy5SzAPIAjAFbB5MAHQBrYAE9iACmx4CRYgEo4WUvfyESAbQC6ANxAA)